# ReWrite in web.config to go between mobile and desktop sites

Tags: mobile, web-config, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, httpcookie

I am finishing up a new mobile website to compliment the desktop version.  Currently I have a rewrite rule in the web.config file on my desktop site that looks like so:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="MobileRedirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="nomobile" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.mysite.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This works perfect if I never want the user to be able to use the desktop site while on a mobile device, but that is not always the case.  Some links on the mobile site DO link back into the desktop version.  I have a link on the footer of the mobile site to "view full site" as well.

So my question IS: how to properly handle cookie setting on that link and then detecting in the web.config and NOT redirecting to the mobile version IF it exists.... I have a conditional check in the web.config for http_cookie "nomobile", but I don't think it is properly working. Do I just send in a querystring value from the mobile and check that in the global.asax file or does that not work because the web.config runs first?

The desktop is a C# MVC4 site on IIS 7.5 if any of that helps, and the mobile site is a simply jquery mobile site.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I have tried checking the querystring in the global.asax file (code below) but it seems that "Request is not available in this context".

```
// create and set cookie if ?nomobile detected
        string forcedesktop = HttpContext.Current.Request["nomobile"];
            if(forcedesktop != null){
                HttpCookie nomobile = new HttpCookie("nomobile");
                Request.Cookies.Add(nomobile);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perfect timing. I was just looking for this exact answer early this morning. Hopefully someone can chime in and help. I will also let you know here if I find the answer while I'm searching.