# Needs for mobile version (www.m.example.com of www.example.com) using Angular 5

Tags: angular, subdomain

I am working on an Angular 5 website, i would like to have 2 versions, one for computer devices and another one for mobile devices, i have seen this post to detect and redirect when the client is a mobile device.

[ReWrite in web.config to go between mobile and desktop sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765043/rewrite-in-web-config-to-go-between-mobile-and-desktop-sites)​

I would like to know if i need a different domain or subdomain to get www.m.example.com working or if i can configure www.example.com to serve this version.

I am not familiar with subdomains, it would probably be an extra cost by my hosting provider. (Now it is very cheap = 20 € /year domain + .Net hosting).

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are in the process of building the website, I would recommend [Mobile First Design](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/) , the reason why many websites have a mobile version is because they were developed prior to many of the technologies which make responsive design easier. This way, you can use the same domain to provide multiple *different* websites to users (including tablets, mobile, TVs and even potentially smart watches), based on screen size rather than detecting the device first.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, thank you i will try this way next website if i can. I have already build the desktop version. In adittion i don´t want both to be exactly the same because i want to to have more things in desktop version that i don´t like to be in the mobile version.

Comment: Hello Chad, may i ask you, in the link you provided me they talk about different layouts depending on the screen size but they don´t say anything about how they show the specific layout in each case. Could you tell me anything about that please?